# Maven build to move resources in current project as well as from a dependency to external directory

Tags: java, maven

I'm building a Java project that will act as a **parent dependency** for other projects.
The project source code will have configuration resources in `src/main/resources`.

Now the **child projects**, will add the **parent as a dependency**.
The child projects will also have their own configuration resources.

During the build, I want both, **the resources of the parent dependency** as well as **the resources of the child project** to be placed together externally in the `${project.build.directory}/config` directory.

The rationale behind this is to externalize all configuration from the deployment artifact.

Any Maven experts out there that can make this happen?

Comment: Best would be to show your pom file...apart from that a parent can't have resources cause it must be packaging `pom` which means there is no code and no resources at all...So you can only have a sibling which contains such things...furthermore why do you need to have resources from `${project.build.directory}/config`? Do you have the need to have different configurations for different environments ? If yes take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin/

Comment: That's a very useful plugin thank you. The reason for putting resources in external `/config` is so that they can be configured by an operations team, if necessary, without a rebuild. (example, changing urls, ports, etc)

The intention wasn't to create a parent POM, but the first project is the foundation/framework for subsequent projects.